# Writeback from Azure AD to on-premises AD: Creating users, groups, etc

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I understand that the Graph API can be used in Azure AD to create,update users, groups etc but can these changes be synced back to the on-premises AD that the Azure AD is integrated with ?

I believe password writebacks were enabled in some recent versions but are writebacks for creating new users, groups supported with a sync from Azure AD to the on prem AD ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can "writeback" users and groups from Azure AD to your on-premises Server AD. Azure AD Connect is the recommended tool to use when configuring synchronization.

Download the latest public preview of the tool here.
http://connect.microsoft.com/site1164/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=53949

There is a document included in the download that explains how and where to setup user and group writeback.